# How to populate related table in Cassandra using CQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, composite-primary-key, nosql

I am trying to practice Cassandra using [this example](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/column_family) (under **Composite Columns** paragraph):

So, I have created table **tweets** and it looks like following:

```
cqlsh:twitter> SELECT * from tweets;

 tweet_id                             | author      | body
--------------------------------------+-------------+--------------
 73954b90-baf7-11e4-a7d0-27983e9e7f51 | gwashington | I chopped...

(1 rows)
```

Now I am trying to populate timeline, which is a related table using CQL and I am not sure how to do it. I have tried SQL approach, but it did not work:

```
cqlsh:twitter> INSERT INTO timeline (user_id, tweet_id, author, body) SELECT 'gmason', 73954b90-baf7-11e4-a7d0-27983e9e7f51, author, body FROM tweets WHERE tweet_id = 73954b90-baf7-11e4-a7d0-27983e9e7f51;
Bad Request: line 1:55 mismatched input 'select' expecting K_VALUES
```

So I have two questions:

1. How to populate **timeline** table with SQL, so that it would relate to **tweets**?
2. How do I make sure that *Timeline Physical Layout* will be created as shown in that example?

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is explanation for my question #2 above (the picture is taken from [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/column_family)):

[image: This is explanation for my question #2 above:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tldr;**

1. Use cqlsh `COPY` to export `tweets`, modify the file, use `COPY` to import `timeline`.
2. Use cassandra-cli to verify the physical structure.

*Long version...*

1. I'll go a different way on this one, and suggest that it will probably be easier using the native `COPY` command in cqlsh.

I followed the similar [examples found here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1).  After creating the `tweets` and `timeline` tables in cqlsh, I inserted rows into `tweets` as indicated.  My `tweets` table then looked like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM tweets;

 tweet_id                             | author      | body
--------------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc |      gmason | Those gentlemen, who will be elected senators, will fix themselves in the federal town, and become citizens of that town more than of your state.
 b67fe644-4dbe-489b-bc71-90f809f88636 |    jmadison |                                                                                  All men having power ought to be distrusted to a certain degree.
 819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1 | gwashington |                                                                    To be prepared for war is one of the most effectual means of preserving peace.
```

I then exported them like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> COPY tweets TO '/home/aploetz/tweets_20150223.txt' 
WITH DELIMITER='|' AND HEADER=true;

3 rows exported in 0.052 seconds.
```

I then edited the `tweets_20150223.txt file`, adding a `user_id` column on the front and copying a couple of rows, like this:

```
userid|tweet_id|author|body
gmason|05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc|gmason|Those gentlemen, who will be elected senators, will fix themselves in the federal town, and become citizens of that town more than of your state.
jmadison|b67fe644-4dbe-489b-bc71-90f809f88636|jmadison|All men having power ought to be distrusted to a certain degree.
gwashington|819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1|gwashington|To be prepared for war is one of the most effectual means of preserving peace.
jmadison|819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1|gwashington|To be prepared for war is one of the most effectual means of preserving peace.
ahamilton|819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1|gwashington|To be prepared for war is one of the most effectual means of preserving peace.
ahamilton|05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc|gmason|Those gentlemen, who will be elected senators, will fix themselves in the federal town, and become citizens of that town more than of your state.
```

I saved that file as `timeline_20150223.txt`, and imported it into the `timeline` table, like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> COPY timeline FROM '/home/aploetz/timeline_20150223.txt' 
WITH DELIMITER='|' AND HEADER=true;

6 rows imported in 0.016 seconds.
```

2. Yes, `timeline` will be a wide-row table, partitioning on `user_id` and then clustering on `tweet_id`.  I verified the "under the hood" structure by running the cassandra-cli tool, and `list`ing the `timeline` column family (table).  Here you can see how the rows are partitioned by `user_id`, and each column has the `tweet_id` uuid as a part of its name:

-

```
[default@stackoverflow] list timeline;
Using default limit of 100
Using default cell limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: ahamilton
=> (name=05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc:, value=, timestamp=1424707827585904)
=> (name=05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc:author, value=676d61736f6e, timestamp=1424707827585904)
=> (name=05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc:body, value=54686f73652067656e746c656d656e2c2077686f2077696c6c20626520656c65637465642073656e61746f72732c2077696c6c20666978207468656d73656c76657320696e20746865206665646572616c20746f776e2c20616e64206265636f6d6520636974697a656e73206f66207468617420746f776e206d6f7265207468616e206f6620796f75722073746174652e, timestamp=1424707827585904)
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:, value=, timestamp=1424707827585715)
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:author, value=6777617368696e67746f6e, timestamp=1424707827585715)
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:body, value=546f20626520707265706172656420666f7220776172206973206f6e65206f6620746865206d6f73742065666665637475616c206d65616e73206f662070726573657276696e672070656163652e, timestamp=1424707827585715)
-------------------
RowKey: gmason
=> (name=05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc:, value=, timestamp=1424707827585150)
=> (name=05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc:author, value=676d61736f6e, timestamp=1424707827585150)
=> (name=05a5f177-f070-486d-b64d-4e2bb28eaecc:body, value=54686f73652067656e746c656d656e2c2077686f2077696c6c20626520656c65637465642073656e61746f72732c2077696c6c20666978207468656d73656c76657320696e20746865206665646572616c20746f776e2c20616e64206265636f6d6520636974697a656e73206f66207468617420746f776e206d6f7265207468616e206f6620796f75722073746174652e, timestamp=1424707827585150)
-------------------
RowKey: gwashington
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:, value=, timestamp=1424707827585475)
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:author, value=6777617368696e67746f6e, timestamp=1424707827585475)
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:body, value=546f20626520707265706172656420666f7220776172206973206f6e65206f6620746865206d6f73742065666665637475616c206d65616e73206f662070726573657276696e672070656163652e, timestamp=1424707827585475)
-------------------
RowKey: jmadison
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:, value=, timestamp=1424707827585597)
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:author, value=6777617368696e67746f6e, timestamp=1424707827585597)
=> (name=819d95e9-356c-4bd5-9ad0-8cd36a7aa5e1:body, value=546f20626520707265706172656420666f7220776172206973206f6e65206f6620746865206d6f73742065666665637475616c206d65616e73206f662070726573657276696e672070656163652e, timestamp=1424707827585597)
=> (name=b67fe644-4dbe-489b-bc71-90f809f88636:, value=, timestamp=1424707827585348)
=> (name=b67fe644-4dbe-489b-bc71-90f809f88636:author, value=6a6d616469736f6e, timestamp=1424707827585348)
=> (name=b67fe644-4dbe-489b-bc71-90f809f88636:body, value=416c6c206d656e20686176696e6720706f776572206f7567687420746f206265206469737472757374656420746f2061206365727461696e206465677265652e, timestamp=1424707827585348)

4 Rows Returned.
Elapsed time: 35 msec(s).
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In order to accomplish this you will need to use an ETL tool. Use either Hadoop or Spark. There is no `INSERT/SELECT` in CQL and this is for a reason. In a real world you will need to execute 2 inserts from your application - one into each table.
2. You will just have to believe that when you have primary key with partition key and clustering key, this would store the data in a wide row format.

Comment: Thanks, Roman. Also,regarding my question #2, I have added the picture of the expected Timeline Physical Layout under EDIT: above. Do you know if that is how "timeline" table would be organized automatically: wide rows? Thanks.

Comment: Bryce has done an amazing job expanding on this answer, while I was too busy during my first day at new job :)